# error while compiling ndk program- permission denied

Tags: android, android-ndk, cygwin, android-ndk-r7

I get this error while compiling an ndk program in cygwin. I don't have any idea why the arm-linux-androideabi-ld.exe file is not getting executed.

```
G:/android/android-ndk-r7-crystax-4/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.4.3/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi/libcrystax_static.a: No such file: Permission denied
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Help me. I'd like to know whether it is a cygwin error or it is a problem in the code ?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah I did chmod a+rwx obj/local/armeabi/libcrystax_static.a and got the permission granted but now it is resulting in a new error. I have searched completely and I cant find any undefined reference

```
ABI='armeabi'
ABI='armeabi-v7a'
ABI='x86'
SharedLibrary  : libcom_graphics_NativeGraphics.so

    ./obj/local/armeabi\libcxcore.a(cxswitcher.o): In function `cvGetModuleInfo':
    G:\android\workspace\anpr4/jni/cxcore/src/cxswitcher.cpp:647: undefined reference to `__mb_sb_limit'
    G:\android\workspace\anpr4/jni/cxcore/src/cxswitcher.cpp:647: undefined reference to `_CurrentRuneLocale'
    ./obj/local/armeabi\libcxcore.a(cxswitcher.o): In function `icvUpdatePluginFuncTab':
    G:\android\workspace\anpr4/jni/cxcore/src/cxswitcher.cpp:381: undefined reference to `__mb_sb_limit'
    G:\android\workspace\anpr4/jni/cxcore/src/cxswitcher.cpp:381: undefined reference to `_CurrentRuneLocale'
    collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
    /cygdrive/g/android/android-ndk-r7-crystax-4/build/core/build-binary.mk:324: recipe for target `obj/local/armeabi/libcom_graphics_NativeGraphics.so' failed
    make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/libcom_graphics_NativeGrap

hics.so] Error 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try chmod the whole ndk directory
chmod <%perm%> <%ndk-dir%>/* -R
use the permissions carefully
this will chmod the whole dir and subdirs.

if you still have problems with your own app and not only the ndk build path,
try chmod command on the project path to.

Comment: This will change the permissions for all directories under root (so, all directories in most case) including /etc/ and other ones that shouldn't be changed and it will make stuff stop working right.